# Moments of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Is it possible to get an upper bound better than $\ll_\sigma T^{3/2-\sigma}$ for $$\int_{0}^{T}|\zeta (\sigma +it)|\,dt,\qquad 0<\sigma<1/2\,?$$

Comment: No.  By Stirling's formula and the functional equation $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|$ is about size $|t|^{1/2 -\sigma} |\zeta(1-\sigma+it)|$.  So what you write is of size $T{1/2-\sigma} \times T$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer is based on Lucia's remark, and is included for completeness.

By (8.111) in Ivić's book "The theory of the Riemann zeta function with applications", we have
$$\int_T^{2T}|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\,dt\asymp_\sigma T,\qquad T\geq 1,\quad 1/2<\sigma<1.$$
Hence, by the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ and Stirling's approximation, we also have
$$\int_T^{2T}|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\,dt\asymp_\sigma T^{3/2-\sigma},\qquad T\geq 1,\quad 0<\sigma<1/2.$$
In particular, the answer to the original question is negative.